# iOS 8 stops streaming audio in background after 10 minutes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, ios8, avfoundation

I have an app that plays streaming audio from a SHOUTcast server. Everything works fine when the app is on the foreground and auto-lock is disabled. The app is however also able to play audio in the background, this feature has always been working fine on iOS 6 and iOS 7. But now my users are reporting that background audio stops after about 10 minutes after they upgraded to iOS 8.

I'm able to reproduce the problem myself by simply running the app on iOS 8. Since the app itself is pretty complicated, I've made a simple demo to show the problem. I'm using Xcode 6 and Base SDK is set to iOS 8. I've added *audio* to *UIBackgroundModes* in my Info.plist. Does anybody know what's wrong with the code below?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.radiofmgold.be/stream.php?ext=pls"];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:streamingURL];
    [self setPlayerItem:playerItem];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player setAllowsExternalPlayback:NO];

    [self setPlayer:player];
    [player play];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please share the fix if you find one. My users are also reporting this problem. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I was also unable to reproduce the problem at first since the problem doesn't occur with all streaming links. The stream in my code however does always stop after ten minutes while it was working fine on iOS 7.
Really annoying since this streaming is the main functionality of my app and I'm overwhelmed with one-star reviews and complaints from users right now. I'll set a bounty on this question ASAP but I'm afraid this is a bug on Apple's part.
I really hope I can fix it myself though.. My app basically relies on this functionality.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm experiencing the same problem. Seems to me like Apple screwed it. In my case the time until the stream stops playing varies pretty much (5 minutes till 12 minutes). It seems that the stream suddenly loses connection and then plays until it runs out of the buffered data. Happens when App is in foreground as well as when it's in the background. The only way to handle it is to observe the state of AVPlayerItem. I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same problem under iOS 8.0.2. My remote audio source plays in mp3.
It seems an internal error is causing the AVAudioSession to restart. You can handle that in different ways:

You can observe the state of the AVPlayerItem.

```
void* YourAudioControllerItemStatusContext = "YourAudioControllerItemStatusContext";
...
@implementation YourAudioController
...
- (void)playStream {
    ...
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:streamUrl];
    [item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:MJAudioControllerItemStatusContext];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == YourAudioControllerItemStatusContext) {
        AVPlayerItem *item = object;
        if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed) {
            [self recoverFromError];
        }
    }
```

This way seems not to be reliable since there can be an immense time delay until the state of the AVPlayerItem changes - if it changes at all.

I debugged through *observeValueForKeyPath* and found out that the state of the AVPlayerItem changes to *AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset* and has an error code *-11819* set.

Since I experienced the AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset error I researched what causes this error - it's the AVAudioSession going crazy. Referring to the [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1749/_index.html) from Apple you should register for the AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotifications. Put that somewhere in your code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionWasReset:) name:AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification object:nil];
```

Then add this method:

```
- (void)audioSessionWasReset:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self recoverFromError];
}
```

In the recoverFromError method try one of the following:

- show an Alert that describes that theres an problem under iOS 8 and the stream needs to be restarted
- restart the stream by setting the AVAudioSession active again and instantiate a new AVPlayer instance with a new AVPlayerItem

At the moment that are the only ways I know how to handle it. The question is why the AudioSession is getting restarted.

**UPDATE**
The release of iOS 8.1 seams to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have also experienced the same issue, and have tested this on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8.0.2 and an iPad Mini Retina running **iOS 8.1 beta 2**, meaning this isn't fixed in the upcoming beta. Both stopped playing the audio after around 30 minutes.

When AVPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed you can log out AVPlayer.status for more detail about the error. I receive: 
`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x178a75bc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.}`

Even when trying to catch this and stop and start my player, I then receive a fatal error to tell me that the AVPlayer has been deallocated. At this point it may be worth trying to reinitialise a new AVPlayer instance as suggested by Hendrik. This still doesn't solve the fact that the audio will temporary cut out as you attempt to reinitialise. Your AVPlayer may also receive notifications before you can reinitialise it, meaning you'll receive a fatal error; this is far from a permanent fix.

Perhaps somebody else will have more luck with this and can provide a more concrete fix. Meanwhile, I have also reported this bug to Apple.

**Update 15 October 2014:** Apple have closed my bug report with this status: Duplicate of 18152675 (Closed).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is fixed in iOS 8.1

Comment: Yes, I ran the sample code in the question and the streaming continued for 30 minutes (after which I stopped it manually).  I wonder why this iOS 8.0 bug didn't affect Pandora and Spotify.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seem to have been fixed with iOS8.1 update. I updated it yesterday and was able to stream for 45 mins whereas before the update, it would crash within 10-15 mins.